# Laravel test Passport::actingAs($user) use routes?

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-passport

I have custom passport user login validation (i made it following [this](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/225#issuecomment-271057428)) so i make my custom `/oauth/token` with this route:

`/routes/auth.php`

```
Route::post('/oauth/token', [
    'uses' => 'Auth\CustomAccessTokenController@issueUserToken'
]);
```

`/app/controllers/auth/CustomAccessTokenController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class CustomAccessTokenController extends Controller
{
    public function issueUserToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        $httpRequest = request();

        if ($httpRequest->grant_type == 'password') {
            $user = User::where('email', $httpRequest->username)->first();
            return $this->issueToken($request);
        }
    }
}
```

If i make a manual `POST` request to `domain.com/oauth/token` is correctly handled by the custom controller but when i use `Passport::actingAs($user);` in a phpunit test not. This `Passport::actingAs();` use the routes or have other way to get the authentication token?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the authentication token using

```
$this->actingAs($user, 'api');
```

Comment: I know, i use `Passport::actingAs()` in the test with the original `Passport` configuration. But what i need to test is my new custom `Passport` endpoints. I still searching i solution but i think i need to build my own helpers and append the token to each test request.

Comment: @Alexd2 This is from a while ago, let me check my code and i let you know how i have this working